# how can I show long texts so that they continue from the bottom line

Tags: flutter

I want the long texts to be clipped and continue from the down line. How can I do this in flutter?
I have tried all the features of "textoverflow" but no changes

[image]

[image]

```html
ListTile(
          onTap: () {},
          visualDensity: VisualDensity(vertical: 4),
          leading: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Text(
                  "Cari Kodu: ${item.cariKod.toString()}",
                ),
              ),
        
            ],
          ),
          trailing: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: [
            
              Text(
                "Bakiye: ${item.bakiye.toString()}" +
                    "${item.dovizIdStr != null ? " ${item.dovizIdStr}" : ""}",
              ),
           
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: wrap with Flexible

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet instead of code-image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just wrap your text inside an Expanded. because the Text widget is inside a Row the widget doesn't know how much horizontal space it has.

Comment: I tried but no change

Comment: oh. and remove that overflow property.

Comment: still same problem

Comment: please share your code.

Comment: the leading property of ListTile is unbounded width. try to wrap your Column inside a SizedBox and give it a width.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So is there any way I can give the "sizedbox" 50% width?

Comment: yes. you can use MediaQuery or LayoutBuilder. but I suggest not to use List tile instead try to make your custom ListTile using card :)

Comment: Thank you, I will follow your advice.

Answer (score 1):

`ConstrainedBox( constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(width: // your Width //),child:// your TextWidget //)`

you can try this with ConstrainedBox Widget you have to give the width whatever you want, it will be automatically wrapped  the text inside the given width